# Using a callback function in javascript to wait for an API response?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen other questions about this, but after two hours of trying different things, I still haven't made it work.

Originally, in my website's JS file, I had this:

```
jQuery.getJSON("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/FB.json?rows=1&api_key=rzH6xM9oAF1phUUPKxoo", function(data1){
    stocksFB = data1.dataset.data[0][1];
});
```

In my window.onload, I have:

```
document.getElementById("stock_area").innerHTML = stocksFB;
```

However, most of the time the text would show undefined. A few times, it would show the correct information. Thus, after a little research I thought I needed a callback function.

I tried a few different things:

```
var getStocks = function(){
    //the same query from above here
};
```

and:

```
function getStocks(){
    getStocksCallback();
};

function getStocksCallback(){
    //the same query from above
};
```

also:

```
function getStocks(function(){
    //the same query from above
});
```

and then an extra `getStocks()` in the onload function for the latter two.

However, the results were always still undefined. Could anyone give me a hint (I'm new to this)?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this if you need a separate function to fill the html :

```
jQuery.getJSON("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/FB.json?rows=1&api_key=rzH6xM9oAF1phUUPKxoo", function(data1){
    stocksFB = data1.dataset.data[0][1];
    showStocks(stocksFB);
});

var showStocks = function(stocks){
    document.getElementById("stock_area").innerHTML = stocks;
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dxn991b7/

Answer (score 1):

Assign the `innerHTML` in the callback from the actual `get` call:

```
jQuery.getJSON("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/FB.json?rows=1&api_key=rzH6xM9oAF1phUUPKxoo", function(data1){
    document.getElementById("stock_area").innerHTML = data1.dataset.data[0][1];
});
```

I'm guessing the reason it works sometimes is because occasionally the call will complete in time, `stocksFB` gets populated, and then the `innerHTML` gets called.

Comment: This answer should work and you don't need a callback function because the getJSON success function already waits for a response back from the api call.  Make sure your script is wrapped in $( document ).ready(function() {  //script here });